# python-requests - user-agent is being overriden

Tags: python, python-requests

I have

```
    logindata = {
        'username': 'me',
        'password': 'blbla'
    }
    payload = {'from':'me', 'lang':'en', 'url':csv_url}
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
    }
    api_url = 'http://dev.mypage.com/admin/app/import/'

    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.post(api_url, data=json.dumps(logindata), headers=headers)

        print s.headers

        # An authorised request.
        r = s.get(api_url, params=payload, headers=headers)
```

I am getting rejected but it is because of 403 forbidden. And I printed the headers, I get:

```
..'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.5 Windows/7'..
```

Why is my `'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'` getting overriden? what am I missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`headers` *are not kept inside session* this way.

You need to either explicitly pass them every time you make a request, or set the [`s.headers`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=session#requests.Session.headers) once:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
```

You can check that the correct headers were sent via inspecting `response.request.headers`:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

    r = s.post(api_url, data=json.dumps(logindata))
    print(r.request.headers)
```

Also see how the [`Session` class](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/sessions.py#L263) is implemented - every time you make a request [it merges the `request.headers` with `headers`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/sessions.py#L374) you have set on the session object:

```
headers=merge_setting(request.headers, self.headers, dict_class=CaseInsensitiveDict),
```

Comment: so, I did ``s.post(url, data=json.dumps(logindata), headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})`` but still getting different headers if I print

Comment: @doniyor ok, what response are you getting from `s.post()` call? what if you omit `json.dumps()` call: `r = s.post(api_url, data=logindata)`?

Comment: from ``s.post()`` I am getting 403. I am trying to login into django admin page. am I missing probably csrftoken?

Comment: @doniyor most likely this is it. Inspect the POST request going to django admin when you do it manually in the browser. If your theory is right, when you'll see `csrfmiddlewaretoken` parameter there.

Comment: yep, that was it. now s.post() is giving 200. but s.get() is still 403 :(

Comment: I think, I need to put csrftoken inside sessionobject?

Answer (score 5):

If you want the session to use specific headers for *all requests* you need to set those headers on the session, explicitly:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    s.post(api_url, data=json.dumps(logindata))

    # An authorised request.
    r = s.get(api_url, params=payload)
```

The `s.headers.update(headers)` line adds your dictionary to the session headers.

Sessions never copy information from *requests* to reuse for other requests. Only information from responses (specifically, the cookies) is captured for reuse.

For more details, see the [`requests` *Session Objects* documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects):

> Sessions can also be used to provide default data to the request methods. This is done by providing data to the properties on a Session object.